# Harmonic analogue of the Weierstrass approximation theorem

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

The Weierstrass approximation theorem says that, given any continuous function $f(x)$ on a closed interval, there is a polynomial which approximates it arbitrarily closely. I'm looking for a theorem of the form

> Given any *nice enough* function $f(x)$ on a closed interval, there is a finite Fourier series $$a_{0}+\sum_{n=1}^k a_n\cos(nx)+b_n\sin(nx)$$ which approximates it arbitrarily closely (*with the possible exception of a finite number of points or even an infinite number of points with measure 0*).

A Google search has turned up [Carleson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleson%27s_theorem) which seems relevant but as I'm not familiar with Fourier analysis I'm not confident making that call.

Comment: I think you will need to add the condition that $f(x+2\pi)=f(x)$ or that the interval in question is $[0,2\pi]$ or else it is obviously false.

Comment: This is a consequence of [Fejér's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fej%C3%A9r%27s_theorem).

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: You should post that as an answer!

Comment: Carleson's Theorem is probably the most general pointwise convergence theorem for the Fourier series: If $f$ is Lebesgue measurable and square integrable on $[0,2\pi]$, then the Fourier transform converges pointwise to $f$ except on a set of measure $0$. This theorem does not address uniform convergence on any particular set. If $f$ is continuous and periodic, then Mario's answer is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you meant by Fourier series here.
Fourier series is very specific in that the coefficients are fixed.
Weierstrass Theorem for periodic function states that:

If $f$ is periodic and continuous in $[-\pi, \pi]$, then given ε $>0$ , there is a trigonometric polynomial $T{_n}(x)$ (what looks like a Fourier series)

$T{_n}(x) = {a_0} + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\left( {{a_k}\cos (kx) + {b_k}\sin (kx)} \right)} $

such that 
$|f(x) - {T_n}(x)| < \varepsilon $ for all $x$ in $[-\pi, \pi]$.

Here the coefficients may be different for different ε .

If you are looking for Fourier series, then you have the celebrated Carleson Hunt Theorem which states that for any periodic function $f$ in the *L<sup>p</sup>* spaces,  ${L^p}[ - \pi ,\pi ]$, $p$ ≥ $2$, its Fourier series converges almost everywhere to $f(x)$.

I.e., there is a set $E$ of measure zero such that for all $x$ in  $[-\pi ,\pi ] - E$,

$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \left( {\frac{{{A_0}}}{2} + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\left( {{A_k}\cos (kx) + {B_k}\sin (kx)} \right)} } \right) = f(x)$,

where $\frac{{{A_0}}}{2} + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\left( {{A_k}\cos (kx) + {B_k}\sin (kx)} \right)} $

is the Fourier series of $f$.

These two possibilities are quite different.

The Carleson Hunt Theorem does not give uniform convergence so you may not be able to approximate the function. For different $x$ you may need different number of terms of the Fourier series to give the same approximation.